# SQL prepared statement mechanics/principle

Tags: sql

I know that prepared statement is used to avoid SQL injection. Just wondering how the mechanic/principle of prepared statement works? Is it different among different programming languages? How does it detect which part is supposed to be functional and which part is user-entered fields?

Comment: The details probably depend on the programming language, database, and API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much about security but rather about efficiency: security comes as a bonus. You certainly realize that queries must be parsed by the server in order to turn them in meaningful instructions for it to execute them. That is the same situation than with regular programmes where source code must be compiled into machine code, but with the compilation work done by the DB server.

The server will have to do that work pretty much each time it receives a SQL query, unless there's a way to tell it to remember a query which must be executed several times. Preparing a query is really telling that to the server.

The second idea is to allow a query to be parameterized,  since often times programmes need to run queries several times with only a few values changing from one iteration to the next. Parameters make this process easily blend with caching query preparations.

As for how this whole process works, as said earlier, this is just [compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). SQL is parsed, transformed into a [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), many transformations are applied on said tree to produce a more optimal version of it, either by eliminating useless clauses, or reformulate them in way which better leverage the structure of the targeted schema. Then the resulting tree is transformed into the stream of instructions that the server will execute each time the `EXECUTE` command will be issued. Depending on the place where parameters are placed in the SQL query, the compilations steps maybe delayed after initial parsing, as values may dictate how the optimization should be conducted.

The main reason why injections cannot work on prepared query is that injections rely on SQL syntax, however after statements are prepared, ie. at the time when the injection data is really submitted to the server, SQL parsing has already been done, so syntactic issues cannot occur anymore. parameters are taken "as-is", without any form of syntactic interpretation within the surrounding query: they are solely coerced to the type required by the expression within which their associated bindings are appearing.

For instance, the classical injection method is to cut short the statement, insert some other commands, and then add a final command to ensure that the trailing SQL code does not proclduce a syntax error.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = ? AND k = 1
```

If in the above query, we replace the question mark by the following: `0; DROP TABLE table`, we realize an injection. The meaning of the statement has been diverted from its original intent, and it will now execute unwanted code. However, the trailing `AND k = 1` will produce a syntax error, so we have to append another command which will syntactically correct the whole string, for instance `; SELECT 0 FROM table WHERE 1 = 1`.

This injection may only work if the placeholder replacement happens before parsing. Otherwise the whole string bound to `?` will be just a string without other syntactic significance. It's coertion to another type (`int`, `enum`, etc.), may produce an error though.

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) on the topic does a much better job at covering it than this humble answer, with many examples and references, don't hesitate to consult it for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on library you use to access your data. This library use to define special escape syntax to define which part of query is going to be substituted and which is static. Like this:

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Customers SET Active = 1 WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

This is C# code which uses ADO.NET data access library. It could basically replace @ID in the runtime with actual parameter value.
Well, in reallity it is more sophisticated since it does caching as well so it sends not yet expanded string to server but we can forget about this caching part for now.